# Cannot feed value of shape (1, 224, 224, 3) for Tensor 'Placeholder_30:0', which has shape '(1, 150528)'

Tags: python

I'm trying to make CNN for my image classification.
Before start that, I'm trying to make one simple neural net model.
but I have error massage that "Cannot feed value of shape (1, 224, 224, 3) for Tensor 'Placeholder_30:0', which has shape '(1, 150528)'"
my image's size are all different... so I resized all image size to 224*224*3 and made model to classify 7labels.. but I met that error and I don't know what to do.
Here is my code please help

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Jan 12 14:46:07 2018

@author: Yoon seock ju
"""
#clear all the variable in spyder
%reset

#import packages
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import misc
import glob
import random
from numpy import array


#InteractiveSession ready
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()


#size for resize image data
size = 224,224

#train, test image list
trainset = []
trainlabel = []
testset = []
testlabel = []

#read train_image data
for i in range(7):
    path = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/향수이미지/train/"+str(i)+"/*.jpg"
    for image_path in glob.glob(path):
        image = misc.imread(image_path)
        print(image.shape)
        if (image.shape[0] >224) and (image.shape[1] > 224):
            print("resize start")
            image = misc.imresize(image,size)
            image = array(image).reshape(1, 224,224,3)
            trainset.append(image)
            trainlabel.append(i)
            print("resize image= ",image.shape)
            print(image.dtype)
    print(i," is done")    


#read test_image data
for i in range(7):
    path = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/향수이미지/test/"+str(i)+"/*.jpg"
    for image_path in glob.glob(path):
        image = misc.imread(image_path)
        print(image.shape)
        if (image.shape[0] >224) and (image.shape[1] > 224):
            print("resize start")
            image = misc.imresize(image,size)
            image = array(image).reshape(1,224,224,3)
            testset.append(image)
            testlabel.append(i)
            print("resize image= ",image.shape)
            print(image.dtype)
    print(i," is done")        

#set placeholder
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [1, 150528])#Our images 224*224*3
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, 7])#Our target

#set Variables
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([150528,7]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([7]))

#start session for initialize variables
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

#soft max & cost function
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))

#training the model
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)



#run train_step
for i in range(1170):
    train_step.run(feed_dict = {x:trainset[i], y_:trainlabel[i]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the line

```
image = array(image).reshape(1,224,224,3)
```

to

```
image = array(image).reshape(1,150528)
```

to make your data's shape match your model's input shape.

Answer (score 0):

> so I resized all image size to 224*224*3 and made model to classify 7labels

No you didn't, because

```
image = array(image).reshape(1,224,224,3)
```

should be

```
image = array(image).reshape(1, 224 * 224 * 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

For others who might be using PIL

```
image = Image.open(file_name))
image = image.convert('RGB')
```